# Configuring FTP to allow specific user to do everything and other users to read-only

Tags: vsftpd

I have to create a new user for ftp ( **vsftpd** ), which I already did  `adduser ftp_user` and make directory ftp itself `mkdir -p /home/ftp/`
Now here is the part I don't fully understand, ftp user needs to have permissions to read and write into that folder, but also other user should only have permissions to read and browse that folder ( or files within it ).
All I did for now is access vsftpd config and added lines:

```
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
```

and added ***ftp_user*** to that list. How do I have that user full rights and set up that directory to be ftp part. Same goes for all other users how do I restrict them to only read and browse permissions?

Edit 1: ftp_user should be an actual account, and by other users I mean multiple accounts ( 4 in my case )

Comment: Is `ftp_user` an actual UNIX/Linux account? When you say "_other user_" do you mean several other users, or just one other user?

Comment: @roaima edited the post, but yes its and actual UNIX account and there are multiple users